# If A is a countable intersection of sets such that they contain one another, then the measure of A is the limit of the measure of the nth set?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Reading Bass Real Analysis https://bass.math.uconn.edu/real.html and don't understand this proof, part 4 of proposition 3.5. The statement itself is intuitive, but I can't wrap my head around the proof.

(4) Suppose  $A_i \in \mathcal{A}$ and $A = \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ and $A_{i+1}\subset A_{i}$. If $\mu(A_1) < \infty$, then we have
$\mu(A)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mu(A_n)$

They then go on to state $\mu(A_1)-\mu(A)=\mu(A_1-A)$.

I'm confused here, because $\mu(A_1-A) = 0$ but $\mu(A_1)-\mu(A) \leq 0$, meaning I'd have to get $\mu(A_1)-\mu(A) \geq 0$ for this statement to be true, but I can't get it.

Can anyone help me understand this part of the proof.

Comment: $A \subset A_1$ so $\mu (A) \leq \mu(A_1)$.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo, please check again.

Comment: @Edd You still have a typo. If you just need $\mu(A_1)-\mu(A) = \mu(A_1-A)$, then observe that $A, A_1-A$ are disjoint and their union is $A_1$, so $\mu(A_1) = \mu(A) +\mu(A_1-A)$.

Comment: @Yanko, Thanks so much, this actually helped a lot. Yes, A is the intersection of all the sets so is contained in A, and then A_1 - A is the rest, leading to the result. Thanks!

Comment: @user14111 Yes, countable sets. And not necessarily Lebesgue, but it could be? They haven't explicitly defined the Lebesgue measure at this point in the book.

Comment: @user14111 you're right. I should have written A is a countable intersection of sets with finite measure.